# Silverlight control adding a scrollbar to the browser window

Tags: html, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, scrollbars

Although new to silverlight, I have produced a clickable map.  [Note:  it is better than using  html tags because the contours of the map match the exact contour of each area, and it is easy to produce a context menu).

I had to resize the map and now it is adding a whole new scrollbar to the browser window:  I now have TWO vertical scrollbars.  Not good for accessibility and usability.

Question is:  Why am I getting this extra scrollbar?

HTML:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" style="padding: 0px; border: 2px solid #999; margin: 5px;
    width: 575px; height: 525px;">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="575" height="525">
        <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/RegionsES.xap" />
        <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration: none">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;
        border: 0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

what it looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: style="margin:0px;border:none;padding:0px"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this looks ok, I would verify the containing HTML holding this div is not the actual culprit overflowing creating the scrollbar.

Somewhere one of you controls height is exceeding the parent element may not be here in the xap/wrapper div but higher up the html tree.

Comment: Thanks, will look at that in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen on any browser or just in IE?

If it's just in IE, probably you are running into the problem I described [here](http://frenk.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/two-silverlight-3-gotchas/).

The solution is to set overflow='hidden' to the _sl_historyFrame div's style.

Comment: Nope, happens in all browsers.